# Закрасить прозрачную картинку по окружности

Tags: css, svg

Есть картинка прозрачная, нужно чтобы фоновый цвет был белым внутри картинки.
 Как такое реализовать?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Нечто подобное делает параметр filter можете попробовать его использовать. А так максимум что css может сделать это подставить под все картинки круглый белый фон в некотором % от размера картинки.
Сделать что то более сложное это уже работа уровня графического редактора. (можно и на js сделать, но мне кажется это того не стоит).

Comment: Не думаю, что стоит вопрос  закрывать... Довольно таки интересны вопрос....Коллеги из очереди проверок, предлагаю вопрос не закрывать...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Делаете `path` в любом подходящем вам редакторе, затем заливаете нужным вам цветом:

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

body {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  background: url("https://i.stack.imgur.com/JsZG5.png") no-repeat center center;

}
```

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="200" height="200" viewBox="310 300 400 400">
  <path stroke="black" fill="white" d="M705.75,497.26c0,16.14-15.86,30-19.77,44.92-4.05,15.44,2.79,35.3-4.9,48.83-7.82,13.76-28.46,18-39.44,29.2s-14.94,31.92-28.54,39.93c-13.44,7.92-33.39,1.33-48.75,5.51-14.88,4-28.68,20-44.82,20s-29.94-15.91-44.82-20c-15.37-4.18-35.31,2.41-48.76-5.51-13.6-8-17.52-28.71-28.54-39.93S365.79,604.77,358,591c-7.69-13.53-.85-33.39-4.9-48.83-3.91-14.9-19.77-28.77-19.77-44.92s15.86-30,19.77-44.92c4.05-15.44-2.79-35.3,4.9-48.83,7.82-13.76,28.46-18,39.44-29.2s14.94-31.92,28.54-39.93c13.44-7.92,33.39-1.33,48.75-5.51,14.88-4,28.68-20,44.82-20s29.94,15.91,44.82,20c15.37,4.18,35.31-2.41,48.76,5.51,13.6,8,17.52,28.71,28.54,39.93s31.62,15.44,39.44,29.2c7.69,13.53.85,33.39,4.9,48.83C689.9,467.24,705.75,481.11,705.75,497.26Z"/>
</svg>
```

Answer (score 0):

Поставить ей самой `background-color:white`?

Comment: background-color не работает как мне нужно https://imgur.com/a/rpKP1

Comment: тогда залить внутренность картинки белым цветом в графическом редакторе.

Comment: @Остин, какой результат вы хотите получить? Как на картинке или заполнить полностью белым цветом волнистый круг?

Comment: @Остин, уточню ещё раз, какой результат вы хотите получить?